# Object not resolving while using WMI for HyperV

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

I am using the official example from Microsoft docs to use WMI to start and shut down the virtual machine but `Utility` and `ReturnCode` objects aren't getting resolved. When I build the application I get

```
CS0103  The name 'Utility' does not exist in the current context
```

I am clueless

```
ManagementObject vm = Utility.GetTargetComputer(vmName, scope);
```

&

```
if ((UInt32)outParams["ReturnValue"] == ReturnCode.Started)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/requeststatechange-msvm-computersystem
Running everything on Server 2019 with Hyper-V running proper.

Here is the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace HyperVSamples
{
    public class RequestStateChangeClass
    {
        public static void RequestStateChange(string vmName, string action)
        {
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\virtualization\v2", null);
            ManagementObject vm = Utility.GetTargetComputer(vmName, scope);

            if (null == vm)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    string.Format(
                    "The virtual machine '{0}' could not be found.",
                    vmName));
            }

            ManagementBaseObject inParams = vm.GetMethodParameters("RequestStateChange");

            const int Enabled = 2;
            const int Disabled = 3;

            if (action.ToLower() == "start")
            {
                inParams["RequestedState"] = Enabled;
            }
            else if (action.ToLower() == "stop")
            {
                inParams["RequestedState"] = Disabled;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Wrong action is specified");
            }

            ManagementBaseObject outParams = vm.InvokeMethod(
                "RequestStateChange",
                inParams,
                null);

            if ((UInt32)outParams["ReturnValue"] == ReturnCode.Started)
            {
                if (Utility.JobCompleted(outParams, scope))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "{0} state was changed successfully.",
                        vmName);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to change virtual system state");
                }
            }
            else if ((UInt32)outParams["ReturnValue"] == ReturnCode.Completed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "{0} state was changed successfully.",
                    vmName);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Change virtual system state failed with error {0}",
                    outParams["ReturnValue"]);
            }

        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args != null && args.Length != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: <application> vmName action");
                Console.WriteLine("action: start|stop");
                return;
            }

            RequestStateChange(args[0], args[1]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Query instead now:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\virtualization\v2");
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(@"SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem WHERE ElementName = '" + vmName + "'");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

ManagementObject vm = null;
foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection)
{
    vm = obj;
    break;
}
```

For the ReturnCode use your own constant instead. You can look them up here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/virtual/requeststatechange-msvm-computersystem

Something like this:

```
if ((UInt32)outParams["ReturnValue"] == 0)
    {
        ...
    }
```

0 == all good. Use UInt32 not UInt16!

Remember to run your app as administrator!